# Python: Parsing JSON Keyerror

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to parse JSON by getting the articles and views to print out from the data inside the link provided. I keep getting an KeyError link through repl or it just prints 'None' in my text editor for the articles and views. My main goal is to make Articles and views as dictionary keys and print it out in alphabetical order.

```
import json
import requests

link = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/01/10"

def making_data(link):
  response = requests.get(link, [])
  data = response.json()
  json_data = data['items']

  for items in json_data:
    article_title = items.get("article")
    views_count = items.get("views")
    print("Article: %s" % article_title)
    print("Views: %s" % views_count)
  return whole_data

making_data(link)
```

I tried making the items to look like this, but I get an error saying "Error: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str":

```
    article_title = items['article']
    views_count = items['views']
```

I'm not really sure how to parse JSON as a dictionary on this one.

Comment: your `items['articles']` is a list and not a string, check my answer below on how to iterate over it and get your result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `items['articles']` is a list and not a string, you need to loop over it and then get `article_title` and `views_count`

```
import json
import requests

link = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/01/10"

def making_data(link):
  response = requests.get(link, [])
  data = response.json()
  json_data = data['items']
  articles_list = []
  for items in json_data:
      articles = items['articles']
      #Iterate over the list of articles
      for article in articles:
          article_title = article.get("article")
          views_count = article.get("views")
          articles_list.append(article_title)
          print("Article: %s" % article_title)
          print("Views: %s" % views_count)

  return sorted(articles_list)


print(making_data(link))
```

The output comes up as

```
Article: Main_Page
Views: 17483936
Article: Special:Search
Views: 2213160
Article: Special:RecentChangesLinked
Views: 412903
Article: Special:CreateAccount
Views: 391595
Article: Robert_Gould_Shaw
....
```

Your sorted list will be

```
['12_Strong', '13_Reasons_Why', "1992_United_States_men's_Olympic_basketball_team", '2004_Indian_Ocean_earthquake_and_tsunami', '2017_in_film', '2017–18_Ashes_series', ...
```

Comment: How do you want your final result to look like, update that in the question, and then I can update the code to make `whole_data` accordingly

Comment: Never mind about the whole_data, but how can I make it in alphabetical order in case if there are duplicates?

Comment: Alphabetical order of Articles?

Comment: You are correct. I added all your article names to a list, and sorted the list alphabetically. If it works, please accept my answer

Comment: His exception says a `dict`, but it turned out to be about a `list`?

Comment: I ran his code and found out the response was a list instead of dict

Answer (score 0):

Your `article_title` or `views_count` is possibly a dict not a string. Json string will be parsed to a dict in Python. To fix:

```
print("Article: %s" % str(article_title))
print("Views: %s" % str(views_count))

# or
article_title = json.dumps(article_title)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error. I've tried dumps before and I will still get an error.

Comment: @smokingpenguin can you post related traceback?

Answer (score 0):

your link has to be in the form

```
link = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/01/10"
```

Comment: It's unrelated to the question.

Comment: That was a little mistake on my part, but I fixed it. I'm still getting an error if I were to fix it.